# how to interpolate property names with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let's suppose I have an array of objects myObjects whose string properties are Alpha, Beta, Gamma, ...

In my View I could display the content with Razor like this

```
<ul>
    @foreach(obj in myObjects){
        <li>@obj.Alpha</li>
        <li>@obj.Beta</li>
        <li>@obj.Gamma</li>
         ...
    }
<ul>
```

But if I want to compact the code, passing an array with the propery names (via ViewBag, for example), and try something like

```
<ul>
    @foreach(obj in myObjects){
        @foreach(name in ViewBag.Names)    
            <li>@obj.@name</li>
        }
    }
<ul>
```

Razor does not interpolate that as *object.property* but would simply output

```
myObjects.Alpha
myObjects.Beta
myObjects.Gamma
....
```

I'm quite sure there are a million ways to get the same result, but since  something like that would work quite easily in PHP or JavaScript and I'm new to Razor I'd like to know more about its features.
I have alreaty tried quite a few things, such as String.Concat, String.Format, and various combination of @ and parentheses, but no luck.

Thanks

Solution:

```
@helper GetPropertyValue(object src, string propName)
     {
         @src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
     }
```

used as

```
@GetPropertyValue(obj,name)
```

I could have added an Extension as Pawel suggested, but I need it only on that one View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your casee you can achieve your goal by reflection. You can create simple extension method:

```
public static void HtmlHelperExtensions
{
     public static object GetPropertyValue(this HtmlHelper html, object src, string propName)
     {
         return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
     }
}
```

then add proper namespace to namespaces node in `web.config` file:

```
<add namespace="htmlhelperclassnamespace" />
```

and use in your code in that way:

```
<li>@Html.GetPropertyValue(obj, name)</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to use plain .NET reflection, perhaps by way of a custom helper extension method defined in your project for an easier use:

`<li>@obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null)</li>`

Comment: Upvoted for quick response and right answer. I have accepted Pawel's because is more complete

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already got a feasible solution. Still, I am posting another way to do it, leveraging the `dynamic` feature of .net. Note that `myObjects` should be list of `ExpandoObject`.

```
<ul>
   @foreach (var obj in myObjects)
        {
            var item = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
            foreach (var name in ViewBag.Names)
            {   
                <li>@item[name]</li>
            }
        }
<ul>
```